# Accessing .SVG file's contentDocument from file input - cross frame issue on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I'm trying to access an SVG's `contentDocument` (and change fill colors for specific paths, but that I don't have a problem with) via JavaScript. The SVG comes from user input. Whenever I try to access the `contentDocument` I get the error:

> (index):41 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument'
>   property from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

As you can see I'm using a local server the but results are the same when accessing the file locally. Here's my code:

```
document.getElementById("input-image").addEventListener("load", function () {
    console.log("image loaded");
    let svgDoc = this.contentDocument;
}, false);

var src = document.getElementById("file-input");
var target = document.getElementById("input-image");
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function (e) {
    target.data = this.result;
};
src.addEventListener("change", function () {
    fr.readAsDataURL(src.files[0]);
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<object data="" type="image/svg+xml" id="input-image" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
<input id="file-input" type="file" accept=".svg" />
```

And here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6zuna1d/).

I know this can be fixed by actually uploading the file to the server and then accessing it locally (as in, on the server) but is there a way to get this to work without introducting server side scripting and uploads?

Comment: ... and the code  posted has been tested to work without error in IE(11) and Firefox after window load. Using both `file://` and `http://localhost/` access.

Comment: Yes, that's why I tagged it with Google Chrome, I guess I should have mentioned that in the body and not just the title. I know it's a Chrome issue, IIRC Chrome is especially sensitive to cross frame data. The thing is, I am writing this tool for myself and I'm a Chrome user so I'd really like it to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion for an alternative method of loading a local svg file into the DOM is to

1. read the file as **text** (let's assume it's ASCII or utf-8 encoding) after selection.
2. write the content to an `iframe` object's document
3. pick up the svgElement from within the iframe.

**Concept code**

This code uses an example string instead of performing step 1.

```
    let svgTest = function() {

    let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    document.body.appendChild(iframe); // insert it in the document, somewhere

    // normally read the svg as text, but here just use an example from
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Getting_Started

    let result = `
        <svg version="1.1"
             baseProfile="full"
             width="300" height="200"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
          <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="green" />
          <text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">SVG</text>
        </svg>
    `;

    // write it to the iframe and close the document
    let doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    doc.write(result)
    doc.close();

    // get the svgElement
    let svgElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
    let svgRect = svgElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    // set iframe size (may need adjustment)
    doc.body.style.margin = "0";
    iframe.width = svgRect.width;
    iframe.height = svgRect.height;

    }; //end of svgTest
    svgTest();
```